# Middle click to open a new tab/close tab in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: unity, 12.04

How do I enable middle mouse clicking?

Comment: What does that even mean? If you want people to answer, please take the time to explain what you're asking.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Take a look at the title...

Comment: It's not clear to me what "open a new tab/close tab" means.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour should be enabled by default with Firefox, it may be that your system is not recognizing middle clicks.

To check whether "middle click open in a new tab" is activated type `about:config` into the URL bar in Firefox (and click the "I'll be careful" button, if prompted).

In the search bar type `middleclick`

[image]

Make sure the Value for browser.tabs.opentabfor.middleclick is set to **true** (if it is "False" then double click to change it)
`

Comment: I've had this problem as well but the value had already been set to **true**. I changed it to **false** and then to **true** again. Now it's working!